# can't read file from my computer in google colab (OpenCV imread returns None)

Tags: python, opencv, path, google-colaboratory

I am working on a Python project on colab and I need to perform the following lines of code:

```
img = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\jesus\Desktop\Signaux\Damaged\Husky.png", 1)
#img = io.imread(r"C:\Users\jesus\Desktop\Signaux\Damaged\Husky.png")

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

It looks like the image wasn't loaded, but I right-clicked the image and directly copied the path, so I don't understand how the path would be wrong. I tried with cv2.imread and io.imread but I have errors in both. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If this code is running "on colab", then a pathname on your own computer is utterly meaningless.

Comment: user error. you expect google colab to have access to your local files. it does not. it can only access data on google servers.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur on 2 scenarios :

1. If the image doesn't exist in the path
2. check if the count variable has a valid number - in your case is a const so its infact correct.